# Implementation of string_view formatted stream ouput

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

While implementing C++1z's `std::basic_string_view` to use it on older compilers, I encountered a problem with the [stream output operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view/operator_ltlt) for it.
Basically, it has to output the contents referenced by the `string_view` while not relying on any null-terminator being present (as `string_view` is not guarantueed to be null-terminated).

Normally, writing overloads for `operator<<` is quite easy since you can rely on already present overloads, and thus do not need to use sentry objects [as mentioned in this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298604/when-should-i-concern-myself-with-stdiostreamsentry).

But in this case, there is no predefined overload for `operator<<` taking a character pointer and a length ([obviously](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)). Because of this I create a temporary `std::string` instance in my current implementation:

```
template< typename TChar, typename TTraits >
auto operator<<(::std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>& p_os, basic_string_view<TChar, TTraits> p_v)
    -> ::std::basic_ostream<TChar, TTraits>&
{
    p_os << p_v.to_string(); // to_string() returns a ::std::string.
    return p_os;
}
```

This works, but I **really** dislike the fact that I have to create a temporary `std::string` instance, because that entails redundantly copying the data and *potential* usage of dynamic memory. This, in my opinion at least, defeats the purpose of using a lightweight reference type.

So my question is:

**What is the best way to implement correct formatted output for my string_view without the overhead?**

---

While researching, I found that LLVM does it like this: (found [here](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/experimental/string_view))

```
// [string.view.io]
template<class _CharT, class _Traits>
basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __sv)
{
    return _VSTD::__put_character_sequence(__os, __sv.data(), __sv.size());
}
```

The implementation of `__put_character_sequence` resides [in this file](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/ostream), **but it makes heavy use of internal functions** to do the formatting. Do I need to reimplement all formatting by myself?

Comment: that formatting is about padding for proper text justification (as in table column formatting) -- that is rarely needed, so it all boils down to your needs: if you are writing a library then somebody will come back and haunt you; you may leave it out if your program does not care about it. Besides, that padding code does not seem complicated nor long -- you just might add it too.

Comment: According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2 operator << for char* can be parametrized with Traits type and traits::length(s) characters will be printed. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Alexey Guseynov Since the length of a `string_view` is a runtime value, I do not see how to use a custom traits type for that, since the construction of it (that I could use to supply my runtime length value) happens somewhere in the `operator<<` overload you mentioned, out of my control.

Comment: @nshct but you just wrote that your overload is not available? if so, then just provide your own implementation of `operator<<` which inserts the `traits::length`.

Comment: @mariusm but that just propagates the problem. I would still need to perform the formatting, which is what I am asking how to do here without accessing internal, undocumented state.

Comment: @nshct the overload with traits should take care of formatting. Have you tried that? Do you have a minimal example? which compiler is this?

Comment: I don't see any real way to avoid handling the formatting on your own. May seem strange (does a bit to me) but such is life sometimes. Fortunately the formatting for a string is pretty minimal.

Comment: @mariusm There is only a overload that accepts a trait type as a type parameter. It is constructed **internally**. There is no way for me to supply my runtime length value, as I said. If, hypothetically, there were another **formatted** output function that would take a trait **object**, this could be done. But there is not.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Sadly, this seems to be true. But how do I even know if I should i.e. pad a string? Isn't that implementation-defined state?

Comment: @nshct if there was a minimal example to reproduce your problem, I could check it for myself and perhaps fix it for you.

Comment: You can retrieve the current width with `ios_base::width()`. You'll also need to look at the `left` vs. `right`, and (if memory serves) `fixed` to figure out where to insert padding, and whether to truncate to the field width (retrieve with `ios_base::fmtflags()`). Um...oh, you'll also need to read the current fill character (with `ios_base::fill()`) if you're going to do padding.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Thanks that is really helpful! Mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can see, you'll have to handle this yourself.

Fortunately, the formatting you need to do for a string-like item is fairly minimal--mostly inserting padding before or after the string if needed.

- To figure out if padding is needed, you'll need to retrieve the stream's current field with using `ios_base::width()`.
- To figure out whether to insert that before or after you write out the string, you'll need to retrieve the left/right flags with `ios_base::fmtflags()`.
- To figure out *what* to insert as the padding, you can call `ios_base::fill()`.
- Finally, I believe you'll need to check the `fixed` flag--if memory serves, with it set, you need to truncate your string if it's longer than the current field width.

So (with an ultra-simplified implementation of `string_view`), code might look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ios>
#include <sstream>

class string_view { 
    char const *data;
    size_t len;
public:
    string_view(char const *data, size_t len) : data(data), len(len) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, string_view const &sv) { 
        std::ostream::sentry s{ os };
        if (s) {
            auto fill = os.fill();
            auto width = os.width();
            bool left = os.flags() & std::ios::left;
            bool right = os.flags() & std::ios::right;
            bool fixed = os.flags() & std::ios::fixed;

            auto pad = [&](size_t width) { while (width--) os.put(fill); };

            if (sv.len < width) {
                auto padding_len = width - sv.len;
                if (right) pad(padding_len);
                os.write(sv.data, sv.len);
                if (left) pad(padding_len);
            }
            else {
                os.write(sv.data, fixed ? width : sv.len);
            }
        }
        os.width(0);
        return os;
    }
};

#ifdef TEST   
void check(std::stringstream &a, std::stringstream &b) {
    static int i;

    ++i;
    if (a.str() != b.str()) {
        std::cout << "Difference in test:" << i << "\n";
        std::cout << "\"" << a.str() << "\"\n";
        std::cout << "\"" << b.str() << "\"\n";
    }
    a.seekp(0);
    b.seekp(0);
}

int main() { 
    char string[] = "Now is the time for every good man to come to the aid of Jerry.";

    std::stringstream test1;
    std::stringstream test2;

    test1 << string_view(string, 3);
    test2 << std::string(string, 3);
    check(test1, test2);

    test1 << string_view(string + 4, 2);
    test2 << string_view(string + 4, 2);
    check(test1, test2);

    test1 << std::setw(10) << std::left << string_view(string, 6);
    test2 << std::setw(10) << std::left << std::string(string, 6);
    check(test1, test2);

    test1 << std::setw(10) << std::right << string_view(string, 6);
    test2 << std::setw(10) << std::right << std::string(string, 6);
    check(test1, test2);

    test1 << std::setw(10) << std::right << string_view(string, sizeof(string));
    test2 << std::setw(10) << std::right << std::string(string, sizeof(string));
    check(test1, test2);

    test1 << std::setw(10) << std::right << std::fixed << string_view(string, sizeof(string));
    test2 << std::setw(10) << std::right << std::fixed << std::string(string, sizeof(string));
    check(test1, test2);
}
#endif
```

Oh--one more detail. Since we're only writing to the stream, not directly to the underlying buffer, I *think* we probably don't actually need to create the `sentry` object in this case. As shown, creating and using it is pretty trivial, but it would undoubtedly be at least some tiny bit faster with it removed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you should just be able to have your insertion operator rely on std::ostream::write. Something like:

```
template<class _CharT, class _Traits>
basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, basic_string_view<_CharT, _Traits> __sv)
{
    __os.write(__sv.data(), __sv.size());
    return __os;
}
```